# Mac software to edit audio track for a video file?

Tags: audio, video, software, video-editing

A couple of times now, I've 'cuffed' a movie to make it family friendly, by reversing any bits of swearing - "We want ze neekuff money, Lebowski" etc.  (the latest was Beetlejuice which has a single f-bomb in the middle).

It's a bit of an involved process, involving extracting the audio stream with ffmpeg, editing it in audacity, then recombining it back with the video stream with ffmpeg again.

Is there any free Mac software that would let me do this in one hit?  Ie, be able to directly edit the audio stream (ideally with a reverse function), and save it straight out into a new video, without mucking about with reencoding and ffmpeg?

Comment: iMovie can reverse a clip, but not just the audio, the video too. It might be simpler to just duck the sound instead… "We want ze f____ money, Lebowski"

Comment: iMovie can import a separate audio track. And some audio editors, like Sound Studio, can import audio directly from video files.